# Gatsby can't reload changes on Windows

Tags: node-gyp, gatsby

There is a project which use Gatsby site generator. I run it on my Windows computer. I've set up it according to [this manual](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-on-windows/). It runs. But when I change some sources, live reload doesn't work. As far as I can see it doesn't compile project when changes appears. 
If I restart the server by hands, my changes are available. 
How can I fix it? Or may be there are any ways to compile changes by handls without restarting the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happen on **Windows** OS only.

I've found the reason why live reload didn't work on Gatsby. It didn't work when the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) **Synchronization settings** contain selected "**safe write**" option. 
According to documentation "*Changed file is first saved in a temporary file. If the save operation succeeds, the file being saved is replaced with the saved file*." When this option is unchecked, live reload on Gatsby works good. 
I don't know why, Grunt works with "**safe write**" option correctly, but Gatsby doesn't.

[image]